# error CS0117: 'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for 'Encrypt'

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, .net

I'm writing a mobile application using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and need to encrypt a file. I tried to use a `File.Encrypt` method but it resulted in following error:

> error CS0117: 'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for
>   'Encrypt'.

How can I cope with this problem?

Comment: Can you post your code?  I assume you're trying to use this [`File.Encrypt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.encrypt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

The reason it won't work is because `File.Encrypt` actually calls the native Win32 function `EncryptFile(LPSTR path)`, which won't be present on a mobile device.

My suggestion as an alternative would be to use the encryption algorithms present in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

`File.Encrypt` does not exist within the mobile .NET runtime.

Try using the [`ProtectedData` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=vs.96%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried to use the Protect method from that class. I've read an example from your link and I added System.Security.Cryptography but the method is unaccessible